# Do I have to feel worn out to be losing weight?

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines, workout, weight-gain, plateau

I am currently trying to lose ten lbs, and was not doing so well, until a few minutes ago I hopped on the scale, and it turns out I've lost 20. That's down significantly more than 10 lbs from when I weighed in before I worked out. I didn't workout very hard, but today was something of a fast day. I allowed myself no extra snacks, no food other than strict meals. I drank 64 oz of water. This was probably at my peak calorie burning time. How did  my weight do this? I assume I will gain it back in a few days, if not already. (I ate dinner afterwards, and can feel my stomach swell.) I am only 17, so its possible that my metabolism is unsteady, although my weight generally is pretty stable.I was actually at plateau the last few weeks. I am positive it's not the scale, my parents say it works consistently for them, as does my sister.

Comment: What's your actual weight? It's physically impossible to lose 20 lbs in one hour. That's 2 1/2 gallons of water; you'd be dead or close.

Comment: My immediate impulse is clothing. I've never seen a twenty pound shift, but I know there's a 10 pound difference between my work clothes and my workout clothes, primarily due to a combination of shoes and stuff in my pockets.

Comment: I went from 128 to 113. This afternoon i still weigh the same. I was wearing shorts and a t-shirt both times... pretty light weight, and barefoot. Did all of my weight loss catch up with me at once? I ate nearly identically today, and have once again drank 64 oz.

Comment: In the absence of something extraordinary happening to you, the simplest explanation is that your abnormal weight loss never existed. For one reason or another your scale gave an aberrant reading.

Comment: It can be good idea to visit doctor, doing some blood tests. If you are worried - take some solid information, from certified sources... Other point is - it can be a problem with measurement. I would see that 15-20 lbs - in the mirror, so if that was not noticed? 1-2 lbs per month - for long term weight losing is something that has no worries according to medical point of view. Third - short time loss goes in toilet visit, sweat... Combine it all, and make *your own* decision.

Comment: I would echo the comments. The most swing I've had in a single day was 11 lbs, and that was on a 120 degree day when I had a mountain bike race. I drank close to 150 oz of water/electrolytes (almost 10 lbs) and still lost 11 lbs to sweat and glycogen depletion. This was over about 4 hours.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by the comments from @Eric Kaufman and @Sean Duggan, losing that kind of weight in an hour is likely not possible and certainly not safe. By comparison, I weight close to 220 lbs and will lost 2 lbs through persperation after one hour high-intensity exercise. I did lose close to 7 pounds once, but that was due to taking a purgative in preparation for a colonoscopy...

The weight loss that you see is therefore probably an artefact:

- Per @Sean Duggan ensure that you are wearing the same/similar clothes at each weigh-in.
- Regardless of the opinion of others, your scale may not be working properly. Try re-taring it. Ensure that it is level. And try a different scale.

Comment: I only have one scale... and see my other comments in response to your other suggestions